# Запуск jar через файл sh в Windows

Tags: java, bat, jar, sh

по заданию проекта должен выслать решение, которое будет запускаться файлом с форматом .bat и .sh, создал bat c кодом

```
java -jar target\Java-12-jar-with-dependencies.jar %1 %2
```

все отлично работает, но никак не могу создать работающий .sh, какой .sh имею сейчас:

```
java -jar target\Java-12-jar-with-dependencies.jar $1 $2
```

выдает ошибку при запуске со строки "Unnable to access ....jar", понимаю что нужно что-то с chmod настроить, подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу изменить свой .sh файл, что-бы все работало в Windows и будет ли так же этот файл запускаться в ОС Linux.Спасибо.

Comment: В `sh` используется прямой слэш.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо, но ошибка осталась :(

Comment: .sh под виндой, что ли, запускаете?

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, а разве нельзя?

Comment: А как? И зачем? .sh это скрипты для линукса.

Comment: @Эникейщик в проекте было задание что-бы .sh тоже был, а с линуксом особо не дружу вот и приходится в windows тестировать

Comment: Какой смысл тестировать под виндовс скрипты для линукса? И как вы его запускаете-то? Через cygwin?

Comment: ``java -jar ./target/Java-12-jar-with-dependencies.jar $1 $2``

Comment: @Эникейщик понял что нет смысла,  но как изменить файл что-бы запускался под Linux?

Comment: я выше написал.

Comment: @Эникейщик понял, спасибо

Comment: @Эникейщик кстати,  изменил код на тот, что Вы кинули, и файл .sh начал запускаться в стандартной командной строке Windows и не нужно никаких дополнительных оболочек, как вы выше описывали)

Comment: И не забываем на Linux поставить chmod +r